# C# prevent CMD from Closing Automatically after running?

Tags: c#, console, console-application, filestream

I  want to prevent CMD from closing automatically after running the program.

Code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        FileStream textfsw = new FileStream("fileone.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write); // CREATING FILE
        StreamWriter textsw = new StreamWriter(textfsw);

        Console.Write(" Enter your ID: ");
        int ID = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write(" Enter your Name: ");
        string Name = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(" Thank you! your logged in as" +Name+ +ID);

        textsw.Close();
        textfsw.Close();

        FileStream textfs = new FileStream("fileone.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); // READING A FILE USING ReadAllLines
        StreamReader textsr = new StreamReader(textfs);

        String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("fileone.txt");
    }
```

Screenshot:
[image: after running screenshot]

I want to show the following after running and prevent cmd from closing:

```
Thank you! your logged in as John Smith 12345
```

Any  answers would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Console.ReadKey()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/471w8d85.aspx), which waits until a single key is pressed (and returns it, but we don't need that in this case).

This is an alternative to [`Console.ReadLine()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline.aspx) and [`Console.Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.console.read.aspx) which need the user to press enter.

---

As an asside, when using file access (and working with objects that implement [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) generally) you should use [`using` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/yh598w02.aspx) to ensure all resources are freed up in all cases:

```
using(FileStream textfs = new FileStream("fileone.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using(StreamReader textsr = new StreamReader(textfs))
    {
        // Do things with textfs and textsr
    }
}
```

Also note that since you're using `File.ReadAllLines` you don't need any of the above as it does it for you.

Comment: @MISHAK You should accept his answer by clicking the green tick below the vote count if it is sufficient. 

I just want to add that using `Process.GetCurrentProcess().WaitForExit()` is another good method of stopping the Console from closing in certain situations.

Answer (score 4):

Use `Console.Read()` at the end to achieve this.

```
Console.WriteLine("Thank you! your logged in as" + Name + ID);
Console.Read();
```

As George mentions, you can also use ReadKey() or you can use ReadLine();